# Add Tachyons to angular 4 cli build

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular 4 template at
https://github.com/ngx-rocket/starter-kit

How can I add a css utilities call Tachyons to the build bundle use angular cli.
since this is pure css file not javascript and not css module as well, so impossible to do require 'Tachyons'  like jquery or bootstrap to include to the build like I can do with other dependency.

Any idea how to do? guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `.angular-cli.json` configuration file, you can specify styles to include (including specifying pure CSS files of the third party packages).

As a result styles section can look like this:

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
    "../node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
    "styles.sass"
  ],
```

More info can be founded in wiki for angular-cli project: [global styles](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-styles)